Google Drive API | Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab при попытке вставить url-ссылку в атрибут src тега img
Моя задача - вывести на сайте изображение из гугл диска. Я имею публичную ссылку, вот непосредственно и она: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-CzE1D-U9QZaobPOr--NAb4EPHPJD4iN/view?usp=drive_link.
Во всех гайдах, что я читал пишут, что нужна прямая ссылка, с чем не поспоришь, поэтому я преобразовал её до такого вида: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1-CzE1D-U9QZaobPOr--NAb4EPHPJD4iN.
Вставив её в атрибут src, я получил ту же самую проблему:

Я начинающий разработчик, поэтому не особо осведомлен о том, как правильно распоряжаться облачными хранилищами, возможно этот способ с ссылкой уже не используют, т.к я видел статью https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd?hl=ru. Вероятно, это не особо связано с проблемой, но это только мои догадки. Также я понимаю, что есть способы, которые позволяют избежать использования url-ссылки, но мне интересно, в чем дело и почему у других работает, а у меня нет.(очевидно, потому что я тупой, но всё же)
Вот сам код, где я использую эту ссылку
<Avatar // не img, но проблема идентична в обоих случаях
      alt={username}
      src={`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1-CzE1D-U9QZaobPOr--NAb4EPHPJD4iN`}
      sx={{
        height: "150px",
        width: "150px",
        position: "relative",
        top: "12%",
        zIndex: "1",
      }}
></Avatar> 

PS: Пытался в самых разных форматах использовать ссылку, получилось только в том случае, когда я вручную вбил ссылку в этот сайт: https://www.labnol.org/embed/google/drive/. Но открытого api на этом сайте я не нашел, поэтому обращаюсь сюда за советом.
